# How can I tell how much time I have left in my Google Colaboratory session?

Tags: google-colaboratory

A Google Colab session expires after 12 hours at the longest. For this reason, I don't know whether it's worth starting to train my model or wait until the session has expired to start a brand new session.

Is there a way to know how long my session has been active for, or, equivalently, how much time I have left on my session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
import time, psutil
uptime = time.time() - psutil.boot_time()
remain = 12*60*60 - uptime
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. Backends expire 12 hours after first use rather than first boot.

Comment: Well, at least it gives an upper limt or a good approximation.

Comment: Is there any chance I can get an idea of how much is left while colab is running my code? I want to know whether my model can be fine-tuned till the last epoch or it'll stop in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

Menu -> Runtime -> View runtime logs

Look at the start time (may be on the last page), then add 12 hours.

Comment: I experienced it to be less than 8 hours, actually I slept so can't comment on exact duration but it's less than 8 hours

Comment: i've seen it run for 13 hours before, so i guess it's random?  https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html says "can be as much as 12 hours"