# Find out remaining time in Google Collab

Tags: jupyter

I am using [Google Collab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb) for some Machine Learning projects, mostly because of the free gpus it is offering and the nice setup.

I know that every 12 hours, the environment is cleaned to prevent overusage.

I would be interested to find a way to see how much time remains in order to save everything I would like to use in the future (e.g. model checkpoints) locally, before they get erased.

Do you know any way to do that?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730536/how-can-i-tell-how-much-time-i-have-left-in-my-google-colaboratory-session

Answer (score 0):

Menu -> Runtime -> View runtime logs

Look at the start time (may be on the last page), then add 12 hours.

If saving doesn't take long, you could save frequently so you don't need to worry about it.